# How to create a Brush with a background in WPF?

Tags: wpf, graphics

I want to create a brush that draws a ellipse on the top-right corner, I tried this:

```
<DrawingBrush Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Right" AlignmentY="Top">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Green">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="60.0" RadiusY="60.0" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

The ellipse is in its position, but the rest area is transparent. Can I create a brush that draws an ellipse on the top-right corner with a non-transparent background? Can I use another brush as background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DrawingBrush` can contain a `DrawingGroup` with multiple drawings, each with its own brush. Here I have added a pale green `RectangleGeometry` that fits behind your ellipse and serves as the background:

```
    <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Right" AlignmentY="Top">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="PaleGreen">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="-60,-60,120,120" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Green">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="60.0" RadiusY="60.0" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
```

Given the requirement to have the background fill all available space, I recommend giving the `Window.Background` the fill brush and then overlaying another element in the upper right corner to contain the ellipse.

Comment: But your brush still has a limited bound. The area outside the rectangle is still transparent. I want the brush to work like first draw with a solid color brush which has an unlimited bound, then an ellipse on the corner.

Comment: @EFanZh Okay; what is the constraint for why this needs to be in a single brush, as opposed to using your background color on the target element and then overlaying another element that contains this ellipse?

Comment: I am writing a window template which layout the control buttons on the top-right corner of the window. The user may want to change the background of the window. The background will need a brush which relative to the top-right corner, and I don't want  my window to have transparent background. If it can't be done, I think I'll modify my template to support this feature.

Comment: @EFanZh Well, the window can only have one background brush, and if you need a fixed size in the upper right then you can't fill the rest of it. I would create an container for the control buttons and put the ellipse in there.

Comment: OK, I think I'll do that. Can you modify your answer so I can accept it and close this question?